# STM32 gcc (arm-none-eabi-gcc) links printf even though it is not used

Tags: gcc, linker, arm, printf, stm32

I can't seem to figure out why some `printf` library functions get linked into my code from libc_nano.a even though I never use any `printf`. It steals at least 2K of valuable flash memory space. I can see the sections `_printf_i`, `_vfprintf_r`, `_vfiprintf_r`, etc. in my linker map file.

I tried

- Wl,--exclude-libs option
- EXCLUDE_FILE(..) in linker script

None of these make the symbols disappear from the map file..

My gcc options:

```
CFLAGS = -Og -Wall -g3 -Wdouble-promotion -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -mfloat-abi=soft -DUSE_HAL_DRIVER

LFLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=soft -specs=nosys.specs -specs=nano.specs -Wl,--gc-sections
```

> arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe (GNU Tools for ARM Embedded Processors) 5.2.1
>   20151202 (re lease) [ARM/embedded-5-branch revision 231848] Copyright
>   (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the
>   source for copying conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for
>   MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

First of all, why do they get linked?
Is there any method to exclude them?

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `-nostdinc` and linking with `-nostdlib` ?

Comment: Yes I did, and strangely enough the code compiles and links successfully, but, size gets so much bigger that it won't fit in the flash memory of the device. I suppose the linker falls back using something else instead of libc_nano.

Answer (score 8):

Tell the linker to generate a cross reference: `-Wl,--cref`

> --cref
>
> Output a cross reference table. If a linker map file is being generated, the cross reference table is printed to the map file.
>   Otherwise, it is printed on the standard output. The format of the
>   table is intentionally simple, so that it may be easily processed by a
>   script if necessary. The symbols are printed out, sorted by name. For
>   each symbol, a list of file names is given. If the symbol is defined,
>   the first file listed is the location of the definition. The remaining
>   files contain references to the symbol.

Look for a line starting with one of the print symbols, and the lines below it.

```
grep -A5 _printf *.map
```

There you'll find the library function that uses printf internally.

Comment: The cross reference table did the magic. My code used assert somewhere which refers to printf and friends. After removing assert, my code size has been reduced by over 4K!